# why super.getClass() in a subclass returns subclass name

Tags: java

I am inside a subclass and when I am trying to find the name of super class, I tried super.getClass() , but it is returning me the name of the subclass only.
Why?

Comment: Maybe add some code and sample output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the parent base class object super.getClass()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294656/how-to-get-the-parent-base-class-object-super-getclass)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getClass().getSuperclass()` should do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294656/how-to-get-the-parent-base-class-object-super-getclass this thread by you suggested of Bad Design , so what will be your recommendation to avoid it

Comment: It depends on the scenario. I don't know what you intend to use it for

Comment: My recommendation would be to avoid reflection altogether if possible.

Comment: as a general rule - yes, but it is applicable in a limited set of scenarios

Answer (score 5):

If you override a method from your superclass (or your superclass's superclass etc.), `super.theMethod()` will invoke the original method instead of the one you overrode it with. If you did not actually override `theMethod`, `super.theMethod()` will act exactly like `theMethod()`.

In this case I assume you did not override `getClass()` (in fact I know you didn't because it's final), so `super.getClass()` acts exactly like `getClass()`, i.e. either way the `getClass` method of the `Object` class is called.

Comment: yes , I agree , but why such design , if super is being mentioned for calling the method , why it is not calling the super class method ,

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary It is. When you call `getClass`, you're calling the method `getClass` defined in `Object`. `Object` is a superclass of your class (even if not the direct superclass), so you are calling the superclass's version of the method. In fact the superclass's version is the only version of that method.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating object of derived class and not super class.. you may try this

```
this.getClass().getSuperClass();
```