# inheritance getter from superclass and subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, getter

Here are my class's feature:
[image]

I have to override toString method to make each class print out:

```
“[Superclass]: [name-of-superclass] ---[subclass]: [name-of-subclass]”
```

and I have getter getDescription for each classes' name

I know for subclasses, they only have to do super.getDescription and this.getDescription.

1. **But I don't understand for the superclass LivingRoomItem, how can it call all the getDescription from its subclass?**

---

EDIT:

```
class livingRoomItem{
    int id;
    double price;
    String color;
    String description = "livingRoomItem";

    livingRoomItem(int id, double price, String color, String description){
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
        this.color = color;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "[Superclass] :" + this.description + "----" + "[subclass]: ";
    }


 public String getDescription() {
    return "livingRoomItem";
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}


class Sofa extends livingRoomItem{
private int seater;

Sofa(int id, double price, String color, String description, int seater){
    super(id, price, color, description);
    this.seater = seater;
}
@Override
public String getDescription(){
    return "Sofa";
}

public int getSeater() {
    return seater;
}

public void setSeater(int seater) {
    this.seater = seater;
}
 @Override
public String toString(){
    return "[Superclass] :" + super.getDescription() + "----" + "[subclass]: "+ this.getDescription() ;
}
```

}

Comment: what is `list.size() <= i`? Usually it would be `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)`

Comment: @KevinO Oh! sorry, I correct it. But the console still have no output for my totalPrice

Comment: Don't do math with `double` or you'll get precision loss and unexpected result. Instead use `java.math.BigDecimal`

Comment: @LudovicRonsin OK! Next time when I coding, I will notice this point. But why my console didn't output anything on my method?

Answer (score 1):

Your line of thinking is right, maybe only your execution is not.

Considering the following classes:

```
public class LivingRoomItem
public class Sofa extends LivingRoomItem
public class Table extends LivingRoomItem
public class Lighting extends LivingRoomItem
```

You can handle all of them as they are `LivingRoomItem`

In your calculatePrice method, you will use the `LivingRoomItem` as expected to handle all the objects:

```
public static BigDecimal calculateTotalPrice(List<LivingRoomItem> items) {
    return items.stream().map(item -> item.getPrice()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Since you are instantiating all the objects as themselves (not as `LivingRoomItem`), and setting the price, it should work properly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sofa sofa = new Sofa();
    sofa.setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(200L));

    Lighting lighting = new Lighting();
    lighting.setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(652L));

    Table table = new Table();
    table.setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(598L));

    System.out.println(PriceUtil.calculateTotalPrice(Arrays.asList(sofa, lighting, table)));
}
```

Result:
[image]

---

I got your point in your `toString`, for the purpose of your exercise you can use the [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator inside your superclass `toString`:

Example (inside your `LivingRoomItem` class):

```
return (this instanceof Sofa ? "Superclass... Subclass: Sofa" : "Regular LivingRoomItem toString");
```

But like I said, I believe it is right to show `Object` as superclass :) And only show `LivingRoomItem` on the subclasses.

Hope I was able to help you!

Comment: Thank you!! Can you tell me how to override the toString method in livingRoomItem to make it return “[Superclass]: [name-of-superclass] ---[subclass]: [name-of-subclass]” ?? (My first question on the top)

Comment: Try to override the toString method on each subclass, and call the getSuperClass() and getClass(). You can.find an example over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790210/why-super-getclass-in-a-subclass-returns-subclass-name&ved=2ahUKEwjkmoSM9_reAhWDTJAKHR9DBcIQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw1Jg3UKAWQQfeYSsHHdfSLa

Comment: Yes, I've already override all the subclass, and they are work. But I am stuck in the superclass livingRoomItem toString method. How can I call all it's subclass's getDescription method? Because when I use getClass().getSuperclass() on my superclass, the output is class java.lang.Object, rather than Sofa, Table, Lighting

Comment: Would you mind edit the question and add your current toString method for all those classes? And just for curiosity, why would you ever need that your superclass see your subclasses, since you are already working with the subclasses?

Comment: I've edited it. Since most subclassed are similar, I just post my superclass livingRoomItem and subclass Sofa. Well... because this is my practice question in java class... We have to familiar with how to use inheritance and override method.

Comment: @ShinYuWu, just complemented the answer. Thanks!