# why can we not return super keyword in java unlike this keyword

Tags: java, super

`super` keyword can be used to access the members of parent class. Apart from this, `super` is also an instance of child class as justified by below code:

```java
class A {
}

class B extends A {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().isInstance(new B()));
        System.out.println(super.getClass().isInstance(new B()));
    }
}

public class InheritanceDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B obj = new B();
        obj.method();
    }
}
```

Output:
true
true

Now, If `super` is the instance of child class as justified above and java allows us to return any instance as per return type then why can we not return `super` as an instance(I tried it with the help of below code but got compile error). On the other hand, we can return `this` as an instance.

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
    public B methodThis() {
        return this;
    }

    public A methodSuper() {
        return super;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Although super is an instance of child class": no it isn't.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There is no other "super" instance you can use, it's the same object and its type is `B`.

Comment: That is not how you can use `super`, you should use `return this`. `super` is only allowed to call a superclass constructor, or to be able to call the implementation of a method in a superclass (instead of the overridden version in the current class).

Comment: @Henry "Although super is an instance of child class": Yes, it is. This can be justified by below code – ```class A { } class B extends A { public void method() { System.out.println(this.getClass().isInstance(new B())); System.out.println(super.getClass().isInstance(new B())); } } public class InheritanceDemo { public static void main(String[] args) { B obj = new B(); obj.method(); } } ```Output is: true true

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , As mentioned in my previous comment, If super is the instance of child class and java allows us to return any instance as per return type then why can not we return "super" as an instance just like this instance.

Comment: @IshwarChandra have a look at the specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8, while `this` is a primary expression, `super` is not.

Comment: Because there is no need for that, that is what `this` is for. Allowing you to return `super` would be ambiguous given how `super.someMethod()` works. If you want the nitty-gritty, read the JLS.

Comment: @IshwarChandra No. This snippet doesn't demonstrate anything, as it only shows that a B instance is an instance of B, [which is self-evident](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790210). In your own terms, this would demonstrate that "a child class is an instance of super", which is true by definition (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294759) for why `this.getClass()` is equivalent to `super.getClass()`; in short, `getClass` is `final`, so you're actually calling `Object`'s implementation, which just returns the class of `this`.)

Answer (score 1):

`this` represents the current instance of an object.
What do you think `super` would represent?

`super` is a reserved keyword in java and is used to call an implementation (of a method or constructor) of a base class.

```
public class A {
      public int testVar = 300;
}

public class B extends A {
      public int testVar = 400;

      public int getSuper() {
            return this.testVar; // returns 400
      }

      public int getThis() {
            return super.testVar; // returns 300
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** - `new SomeType()` creates and allocates only one object, an instance of `SomeType` in the heap, and it doesn't create objects of entire chain of `SomeType`'s parent classes. Members of the parent classes, however, are referenced dynamically at run-time. So, while you can access the super-class member with `super` keyword, it doesn't mean that instances of the super-classes are also created.

---

**Details:**

There are **two important concepts** to understand in order to fully answer your question:

1. When we instantiate an object of let's say type `X`, are the objects of its immediate parent and grandparent and etc. (entire hierarchy of the parent classes, starting from the type in question, until and including Object class) also created?

> Due to the fact, that every constructor does an implicit call, as its first instruction, to its immediate parent class constructor with `super()`, some people think, that JVM's runtime system instantiates entire chain of the parent classes as well. If our `class X extends Y` and `class Y extends Z`, people think, that executing `new X();` will implicitly execute `new Y()` (as constructor of `X` calls constructor of `Y`), then `new Z();`(as constructor of `Y` calls constructor of `Z`), and finally `new Object()`, as `Object` is the top-most super class of entire ecosystem in `Java`.
> This assumption is ***wrong***, as during the instantiation of the object `new X();` *only instance* which gets created in the heap is the instance of class `X`. Hence, returning `super` from the object's method will not work, as there's no super-class instance, on the heap, to be returned;

2. If the parent classes are not instantiated, then how the members of the super classes are made available to the child class? are they copied to the derived child classes?

> Not exactly ***copied***, however, bytecode of the parent class members (fields, methods) [are referenced at run-time] from the child class[1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/236062/357261).