# How to know if some class extends JWindow class?

Tags: java, swing, class, jwindow

Is there some method how to know if class extends `JWindow`? For example:

```
class DialogWindow extends JWindow {
}
```

How to check if `DialogWindow` class extends `JWindow` class? I need to know the parent `Window` of some component which may be placed on some `JPanel` which could be placed again on some `JPanel`, and so on on top of `DialogWindow`. Of course, I can pass parent instance argument to some component, but maybe there is some better way to do it?

Comment: Simple `instanceof` check should suffice.

Comment: But if I have for example `DialogWIndow_1`, `DialogWindow_2`,... then I have to compare to every one of them, which is I do not want to do.

Comment: Enlighten us with more detail.

Comment: With some help answered the question myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using instanceof like this :

```
if(DialogWindow instanceof JWindow){//must return true in your case
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, definitely, that was the answer. Thanks @Ben

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it is (thanks to @Ben of course :) ):

```
Container window = getParent();

    while(!(window instanceof JWindow)){
        window = window.getParent();
    }

JWindow parent = (JWindow) window;

System.out.println(parent.getClass());
```

And the output is: `class ...DialogWindow`
Super!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `getClass().getSuperClass()` . A similar question was asked here [How to get the parent base class object super.getClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294656/how-to-get-the-parent-base-class-object-super-getclass)