# How to get this.getClass().getConstructor of a super class?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

Is there a way for me to get a `super` implementation directly through `getContructor`? I want to call the constructor on "this class or any superclass".

The scenario details are that I have a base class that builds its data using reflection but the data is coming in from an external file. The external loader has a lookup that checks to see if data exists for a particular class and all of that is wrapped into `ImplementedCard`, below.

This works fine (enough) and isn't directly related to the question aside from my needing to be able to create all of these instances starting from an `ImplementedCard` instance:

```
public class Card implements DeepCopyable<Card> {
   protected ImplementedCardList.ImplementedCard implementedCard;

   public Card() {
        this.implementedCard = ImplementedCardList.getInstance().getCardForClass(this.getClass());
        this.initFromImplementedCard(this.implementedCard);
    }

    public Card(ImplementedCardList.ImplementedCard implementedCard) {
        this.implementedCard = implementedCard;
        this.initFromImplementedCard(this.implementedCard);
    }

    public void initFromImplementedCard(ImplementedCardList.ImplementedCard implementedCard) {
        if (implementedCard != null) {
            this.name_ = implementedCard.name_;
            /* ... and so on */
       }
    }

    // This deepCopy pattern is required because we use the class of each card to recreate it under certain circumstances
    @Override
    public Card deepCopy() {
        Card copy = null;
        try {
            try {
                copy = this.getClass().getConstructor(ImplementedCardList.ImplementedCard.class).newInstance(this.implementedCard);
            } catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {
                if(!this.getClass().equals(TestHero.class)) {
                    log.warn(this.getClass().toString() + " is missing ImplementedCard constructor");
                }
                copy = getClass().newInstance();
            } catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
                log.error("InvocationTargetException error", e);
                copy = getClass().newInstance();
            }
        } catch(InstantiationException e) {
            log.error("instantiation error", e);
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            log.error("illegal access error", e);
        }
        if (copy == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to instantiate card.");
        }

        copy.name_ = this.name_;
        /* ... and so on */

        return copy;
    }
}
```

This base class is then extended like so:

```
public class Minion extends Card implements CardEndTurnInterface, CardStartTurnInterface {
    public Minion() {
        super();
    }

    public Minion(ImplementedCardList.ImplementedCard implementedCard) {
        super(implementedCard);
    }

    @Override
    public void initFromImplementedCard(ImplementedCardList.ImplementedCard implementedCard) {
        if (implementedCard != null) {
            super.initFromImplementedCard(implementedCard);

            /* custom init goes here */
        }
    }

    /* other class details follow */
}

public abstract class Hero extends Minion implements MinionSummonedInterface {
    public Hero() {
        super();
    }

    public Hero(ImplementedCardList.ImplementedCard implementedCard) {
        super(implementedCard);
    }

    /* no custom init; other class details follow */
}

public class Hunter extends Hero {
    public Hunter() {
        super();
    }

    public Hunter(ImplementedCardList.ImplementedCard implementedCard) {
        super(implementedCard);
    }

    /* no custom init; other class details follow */
}
```

This goes on for hundreds of classes. What I want to do is pull out the constructors that do nothing but call `super` with the same parameters but when I do, it breaks the `getConstructor` call in `deepCopy`.

Comment: For those curious, you can see the full code here: https://github.com/MrHen/HearthSim/blob/2eda222ad03373b139ed0280e4db30d9756df91e/src/main/java/com/hearthsim/card/Card.java.

Comment: I'm not understanding the close vote. The code works as written perfectly fine. I am looking for a specific improvement; not debugging.

Answer (score 2):

For each class, you can do:

```
Hero h = new Hero();
Class hc = h.getClass();

// Get super class and its constructor.
Class<?> sc = hc.getSuperclass();
Constructor scConst = sc.getConstructor(ImplementedCard.class);

// Get super class's parent and its constructor.
Class<?> ssc = sc.getSuperclass();
Constructor sscConst = ssc.getConstructor(ImplementedCard.class);
```

You could also put this in a loop until you get to Object.class or some other point in the class hierarchy where you'd like to break.

Comment: This will presumably create an object of type `sc` or `ssc` though, right? I still need an instance of `Hero`.

Answer (score 1):

As @nhylated suggested, try

```
this.getClass().getSuperClass()
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294759) is a nice explanation regarding why

```
super.getClass()
```

behaves like it does.