# How to retrieve the parent of main class file

Tags: java, class, parent-child, program-entry-point

Without using the `getProtectionDomain()` method, how could I print the parent of a class?

For example

```
class Hi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Hi.class. How can I retrieve the parent of Hi.class?
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the parent of the class, or the parent of the method (calling method in call tree), or the parent ClassLoader?

Comment: Or do you mean the source file from which the Java file was compiled?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`Hi.class.getSuperclass();`

To get the parent class of the class that your method currently resides in.

If you want something else, please describe what it is you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you din't inherit any class. So, by default in java every class inherits java.lang.Object class.

for that you can use Hi.class.getSuperclass()

Comment: It's actually getSuperclass().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getSuperclass()` api

```
getClass().getSuperclass()
```

But don't use this. It is certainly a sign of bad design.

[It is copied from, For details read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294656/how-to-get-the-parent-base-class-object-super-getclass)

Comment: At least cite your sources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294656/how-to-get-the-parent-base-class-object-super-getclass